# Expressing the CHSH inequality in terms of probability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability

Let's say we have a distribution which gives the probabilities $\mathbb{P}(a,b|x,y)$, where $a,b$ are the outputs of a quantum channel for Alice and Bob respectively, and $x,y$ are the inputs (also for Alice and Bob respectively). Moreover, as usual, $a,b,x,y \in \{0,1\}$

The most common form of the CHSH inequality that I see is that one on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality, but when I was talking to one of my professors, he said that another equivalent expression is

$$-1 \leq \mathbb{P}(00|00) - \mathbb{P}(01|01) - \mathbb{P}(10|10) - \mathbb{P}(00|11) \leq 0$$

Is there any place where I can see the proof of the equivalency between these two expressions?

Comment: if I remember correctly, if you use $0$ and $1$ rather than $\pm1$ as outcomes you get something like $0\le S \le 2$ instead of $|S|\le2$. You seem to be using $-S$ in your expression, so maybe it's just this?